# System.StackOverflowException in datagridview in virtual mode

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

Put a datagridview in vb .net 2010 form, then on the form load, put this code.

```
   Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        dg.VirtualMode = True
        dg.Columns.Add("a", "a")
        dg.RowCount = 30000
        dg.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = dg.RowCount - 1
    End Sub
```

Run the project. After some seconds, it crashes with System.StackOverflowException.
Someone have an idea of what happens? Seems a bug.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show any additional code that you may have for events on the DataGridView? Somewhere you may have code that is infinitely recursive.

Comment: Without seeing your `VirtualMode` event handlers, the only guess I can hazard is that in one or more of your handlers, you're manipulating the `DataGridView` directly instead of using (for example) `e.Value` to provide a retrieved value. See [MSDN's article on Virtual Mode in the DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171622.aspx) for more information and examples.

Comment: I started a new project in VS2010 with only this code, and it doesn't crash... Did you test it with an empty project too?

Comment: There are no more code. Is only this; no event handlers, nothing more. It crashes even if I do a new application and only do what I say.

Comment: Here I put the source and also the .exe that crashes: http://www.fileserve.com/file/zR2QQaf/WindowsApplication1.zip

Comment: Ok. Is a problem with my computer. I put the application in another one and don't crashes. I will reinstall visual studio. Thanks and sorry. How to mark this as solved?

Comment: @user1034156: You'd have to answer your own question and accept it. But I'm not sure I would bother because you didn't find the root cause, just sidestep the problem ;-) Maybe it has something to do with a missing Windows or VS update, or the .NET framework target version?

Answer (score 0):

the error is because dg.rowcount field is readonly and you have assigned a value to it.
and set the project mode to debug rather than release so that you can see the exact error.
remove this line:

> dg.rowcount = 30000  and it should work just fine.